# Knockout onpaste event

Tags: knockout.js

I was wondering if there is a way to do this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/HzkCw/1/ in knockout?

I am struggling to get the pasted value on the event.  I am abble to trigger it using

```
self.onScan = function (d, e) {
            var inputDate = e;
            setTimeout(function () {
                var theData = inputDate.target.value;
                console.log(theData );
            }, 100);

        };
```

and the element is binded by

```
data-bind="event:{ onpaste: onScan }
```

but just fail to get the value.  Even tried to bind the value to an observable but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to pasted text from clipboard that provided with event.

```js
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    
    self.pastedText = ko.observable("Start");
    
    self.onPaste = function (vm, event) {
        var text = event.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
        self.pastedText(text);
        
        // Indicate that text could be added into textbox
        return true;
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="content-placeholder">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Paste text" data-bind="event:{ paste: onPaste }">
  <div data-bind="text: pastedText"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I marked this as the answer.  It seems to be working on another pc I tried it on but not on mine.  I ended up doing it differently and works on both machines.

My machine kept on throwing undefined for clipboardData

Answer (score 1):

As a small addition to, Romaniuk's question, KnockoutJS makes its own event to pass in, which doesn't have the `clipboardData` variable in it. To reach the clipboardData, you need to access `originalEvent.clipboardData`:

```
self.onPaste = function (vm, event) {
    var text = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData("text/plain");
    self.pastedText(text);
    
    // Indicate that text could be added into textbox
    return true;
}
```